# How to get the benefits of /EHa with /EHsc, on a particular function?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, seh, structured-exception

If I know that a particular `extern "C"` function in my program (say, `RaiseException`) is the only function that raises SEH exceptions, and I want them converted to C++ exceptions, is there any way for me to "selectively enable" `/EHa` for that function, so that the exceptions get converted to `CStructured_Exception` without bloating or slowing down the rest of the program as [normally caused by `/EHa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx)?

Comment: No, it needs to be active at the call site.  Provide evidence that those two cpu instructions *really* slow down your code.  Long ago eliminated.  Right now the "omigod, it's sucks mud" is a fishing expedition without merit.

Comment: @HansPassant: Microsoft *itself* says (even in the VS 2012 docs) that *"`/EHa` may result in a less performant image because the compiler will not optimize a `try` block as aggressively, even if the compiler does not see a `throw`"*, and I don't think they're making a mistake when they say that (feel free to correct me). As for the code bloat (which is *not* mentioned), it's real: my executables get around ~10-20% bigger with `/EHa`. I never said it "sucks" (heck, at least `/EHa` is available), I just find it unnecessary to bloat my executables for something I don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's obviously no compiler option to do that.  Maybe:

```
void RaiseException() {
   __try {
      // do something that might throw here...
   }

   __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {   
      throw std::exception("structured exception");
   }
}
```

Comment: I *could* make a wrapper function, but it feels kind of weird to throw, catch, and then throw again, just so I can get an `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` structure to feed into `CStructured_Exception`. Still, it's a valid alternative I guess... +1